# GWT i18n and images

Tags: gwt, internationalization, image

Is there some way to easily internationalize images (using g:Image and ImageResource) in GWT?
From what I can see, it is possible to internationalize the src attribute of a img element, using:

```
<img src="http://www.images.com/englishVersionOfImage.png" alt="">
<ui:attribute name="src" description="Image to be internationalized"/>
</img>
```

and by changing the src value in the appropriate LocalizableResource_xxxx.properties file.

However, this technique does not seem to be applicable to 
`<g:Image resource="{resources.MyImageResource}"/>` elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be as simple as with all other source types (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#I18N). 
In simple words, if you use something like this for text labels:

- Messages.properties
- Messages_fr.properties
- Messages_de.properties

, then try the same technique with images:

- logo.jpg
- logo_fr.jpg
- logo_de.jpg

The proper file should have been chosen depending on current locale.

So, considering the example from https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Using_an_external_resource  use:

```
<g:Image resource='{res.logo}'/>
```

and then have a class

```
/**
  * Resources used by the entire application.
*/
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

  @Source("Logo.jpg")
  ImageResource logo();
...
```